# "No se hable más" - Why the "se"?

Tags: modismos, conjugación, reflexivos

As I read in [this entry of Español Avanzado](https://www.espanolavanzado.com/significados/1130-no-se-hable-mas-no-se-habla-mas), ***no se hable más*** is a fix term to tell someone to not talk about this (topic) anymore. My question is: where does the "se" come from? What would be the difference between "no se hable más" and "no hable más". Is "hablar" in this case reflexive? If so, why?

Comment: RAE: no se hable más de, o en, ello

1. exprs. U. para cortar una conversación, o componer y dar por concluido un negocio o disgusto.

It means: There is nothing more to discuss or be said. It's an idiom.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's an interesting usage of *[se](https://www.rae.es/dpd/se)*. The verb *hablar* (as many others) can be used in an impersonal way if you don't want to specify who is talking about something or you just simply don't know who is talking. Example:

> Se habla mucho acerca del divorcio de esa pareja.
>
> *People are talking a lot about the divorce of that couple.*
> or
> *A lot is being said about the divorce of that couple.*

Example with a different verb:

> Se trabaja mejor en equipo.
>
> *You can work better if you're part of a team.*

And even with copulative verbs:

> Se es más feliz sin responsabilidades.
>
> *One can be happier without responsibilities.*

So if you think that nobody should talk any more about a subject, but you don't want to address to anyone in particular, you can use that same impersonal *se* and say:

> No se hable más.

Note that this does not make the use of the verb *hablar* reflexive, as people are not talking to themselves, but to other people.

If you say *no hable más* you are using the imperative negative form, addressing to the person in front of you, and saying "you, do not talk any more".

> *—Bien dezís —dixo el Rey—, y por agora no se hable más.*
>
> Garci Rodríguez de Montalvo, "Amadís de Gaula, libros I y II", 1482-1492 (Spain).

Comment: Typo, people _are_ not _is_ (twice)

Comment: @mdewey fixed. I got carried by the Spanish "la gente habla" and not "hablan".

Comment: I, of course, suffer from the reverse problem.

Comment: It’s almost like it has an unsaid, implicit *que...* before the *no se hable más*, maybe even a silent *quiero que...* or *se quiere que...*. ♬  [*“Y que no me digan en la esquina”*](https://genius.com/Los-cantantes-el-venao-lyrics) ♬

Answer (score 2):

**No hable más**.... Can be translated to "Do not speak anymore."

**No se hable más**.. Can be translated to "Let there be no more speaking."

You wouldn't directly tell a person "**no se hable más**." You would use "**no hable más**."

You could use **"no se hable más"** when addressing a group, and you a trying to tell them to stop speaking.

Comment: We really don't say: Let there be no talking. We just say: No talking. Or even: Let's stop talking, renders the subjunctive.

Answer (score 2):

Pertaining to [your concrete saying *(modismo)*](https://www.espanolavanzado.com/significados/1130-no-se-hable-mas-no-se-habla-mas):

> *Me pagas 50 euros y no se hable más (del tema).*

| form | *castellano* | [literal] translation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| imperative 2nd person *(tú)* | *y no hable**s** más del tema.* | and no longer talk about it. |
| imperative 3rd person *(Usted)* | *y no hable más del tema.* | and no longer talk about it. |
| impersonal form | *y no **se** hable más del tema.* | [and **one** no longer talks about it.] = and let's no longer talk about it. |

So, the Spanish *"se"* translates to the English impersonal "one" in this case.

Besides that use, the impersonal form could also be employed in the following circumstances:

- To express a general truth or expected way of behaviour, e.g. to correct a young child *"¡A la hora de dormir no se hable más!"*
- In ordering a group of persons to be quiet e.g. a class of students *¡No se hable más!* (more common in Latin America.) However, a *¡Silencio!* would be more effective in such a case.

Comment: y no se hable más del tema would be better translated as it is no longer talked about.